# ASP.net AJAX Drag/Drop?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I wonder if someone knows if there is a pre-made solution for this: I have a List on an ASP.net Website, and I want that the User is able to re-sort the list through Drag and Drop. Additionally, I would love to have a second list to which the user can drag items from the first list onto.

So far, I found two solutions:

- The ReorderList from the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit), which requires a bit of manual work to make sure changes [are persisted](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/PersistentReorderList.aspx) into the database, and that does not support drag/drop between lists.
- The [RadGrid](http://www.telerik.com/DEMOS/ASPNET/Prometheus/Grid/Examples/Programming/DragAndDrop/DefaultCS.aspx) from Telerik which does all I want, but is priced far far beyond my Budget.

Does anyone else have some ideas or at least some keywords/pointers to do further investigation on? Espectially the Drag/Drop between two lists is something I am rather clueless about how to do that in ASP.net.

Target Framework is 3.0 by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mootools sortables plugin does just that, and best of all, it's free ;)

http://demos.mootools.net/Sortables

Comment: any way to bind this to the database?

Answer (score 2):

This is just personal opinion, but the problem I find with ready-made controls in cases like this is that they are extremely bloated, because they're trying to fit everybody's purpose.  If all you need is a sortable list then a simple [Scriptaculous list](http://demo.script.aculo.us/ajax/sortable_elements) or [jQuery list](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortables/sortable) with a quick WebMethod callback should fit the bill quite nicely, and you can obviously stick this into your own user control.

As I say, just my opinion, but I wouldn't go spending money on something that's going to add tons of overhead to my page, when I could spend (literally) 10 minutes writing one for free.

Answer (score 1):

I've evaluated the [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) grid as well as [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/Default.aspx) version.  In the end we took an approach similar to what tags2k suggested.  We just wrote our own javascript and called [.Net PageMethods](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx) to do the server side work.

We found both of the "out of the box" solutions to be bloated.  Unless you put paging in at like 20 records per row they really stunk performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Raj Kaimal's ajax control extender:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/Contents/Item/Display/517

It works like a charm.