# Can i use the Drag and Drop of HTML 5 in my asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, html, drag-and-drop

I know this question is quite basic but since there is lot of confusion what can be used and not from the HTML 5 tags i wanna know if i can use drag and drop feature of HTML5 in my asp application? There is no code yet, so sorry about that. Scenario is that there is a tree view with a list of details about students, if these details are stored in a table, i want to drag and drop their ids(only the text not the whole table or row) from the table to my select query. is it possible? i went through the following questions but didn't get a clear picture 
[ASP.net AJAX Drag/Drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589/asp-net-ajax-drag-drop)  and [Creating a drag and drop application in ASP.NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709825/creating-a-drag-and-drop-application-in-asp-net-3-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.  ASP.NET is a backend product that generates HTML and sends it down to client browsers.  The question of whether or not ASP.NET can generate HTML5 markup isn't as important as making sure that your audience will be using a browser that supports the features of HTML5 that you wish to implement in your app.

More to the point, however, is that 99% of the drag-and-drop implementations you'll find on the internet use a JavaScript framework (jQuery, YUI, AJAX Control Toolkit, etc). While ASP.NET might be the vehicle you use to deliver the javascript to the browser, it in-and-of-itself is not responsible for creating drag-and-drop application -- it is the javascript that creates the dynamic nature of the app in the browser.

Where ASP.NET gets involved is handling the updates/ajax requests that your client-side javascript app sends to it.  Using your app as an example: dragging the student ID to your query would be done with javascript on the client, and the javascript would then send the query to your ASP.NET backend which would process the information and send the results back to your app in the browser (assuming it was a true ajax application).

Examples:

[jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

[YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/dragdrop/dd-basic.html)

Comment: If there is a tree then user selects a node and drags it and drops it else where (not another tree). then only the text in the node of that tree must be dropped is this possible to achieve??? pls pls reply.. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's possible to achieve. But like I said -- you're not going to be able to accomplish this on the server.  You're going to have to use one of the javascript frameworks I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use any valid HTML code inside the ASP.net code as well. finally ASP.net code will be converted into pure HTML. so you can use any valid html code. for more details on how to implement [HTML5 drag and drop](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. If i want to drag text from a table and drop it else where its possible then.?

Comment: you cannot drag only text from any language.if you wrap the text with any html container, you can do drag and drop for that.

Comment: If there is a tree then user selects a node and drags it and drops it else where (not another tree). then only the text in the node of that tree must be dropped is this possible to achieve??? pls pls reply.. Thank you

Comment: see [this link](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/TreeView.aspx). final out put of the review. so you can use drag and drop for this.